# Setting a Document Sets Columns via Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I have been trying to create multiple Document Sets using Powershell from a csv file.

The script creates the Document Sets with the correct Name but doesnt set them up with the Metadata needed for the document set.

For example

I am creating 100 document sets - Each with a Unique Name and should have certain properties populated at creation.
Project Number
Project Lead
Porfolio Lead

However i cannot get the 3 fields above to populate in the Respective Columns even though they are part of the content type for the Document Set.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\Projects.csv

#Script settings
$webUrl = "http://spprojects/"
$listName = "New Doc Set"


### Get web and list
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

### Get Document Set Content Type from list
$cType = $list.ContentTypes["MY Doc Set"]

# Create desired number of subfolders
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
$pn = $line.PorfoiloLead
$PPn = $line.ProjectLead
$name = $line.ProjectNumber
[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{}
$docsetProperties.add('PortfolioLead',$pn)   
$docsetProperties.add('ProjectLead',$ppn) 

    $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($list.RootFolder,$Name,$cType.Id, $docsetProperties)
write-host "$name ... created"
}

$web.Dispose()
```

I have tried the example script located at http://www.the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Create-Multiple-Document-Sets-with-Powershell and that has the same behaviour of creating the Doc Sets but not importing the data into the columns for the Document set.

However i can see when I look to call the Doc Set Properties that it has been set there - however this is not displaying at all in the Library when i view it in the browser.

Hopefully I'm just having a bad day (or 2) and this is a relatively simple issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue - I have to use the Internal Name for the Field Which in this case was the name1

```
$newDocumentSet.Folder.Properties["PortfolioLead1"]=$pN
$newDocumentSet.Folder.Properties["ProjectLead1"]=$ppN
$newDocumentSet.Folder.Update()
$list.Update()
$web.Update()
```

Once i have included it this was it is now updating as originally required.

Comment: great you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Try to create document set first and then user the resulting object to update the metadata.

i.e.

```
 $newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($list.RootFolder,$Name,$cType.Id, $docsetProperties)

// set properties 

// update item 

  write-host "$name ... created"
```

I have not tried to execute the powershell but had simple steps through C# code.

Comment: Hi Monica,
I have tried some methods to then update this property including

   $newDocumentSet.Folder.Properties["PortfolioLead"]=$pN
   $newDocumentSet.Folder.Update()
   $list.Update()
   $web.Update()

However this still doesnt force it through when accessing via Browser (although i can see it in the Properties of the Folder when i check this via Powershell)